# How to obtain Wide Function in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, area, function

Is there a way to compute the wide function in QGIS?. I want to obtain this function to compare the topology of two stream networks.

According to Bras (1990) the wide geometrical function N(x) measures the number of channels at a distance from the outlet of the basin. The distance **x** can be geometrical (i.e. real distance) or topological (measured in terms of the number channels from the outlet of the basin)

[image: Taken from: Giraldo 2005]

References.

Bras, R. L.  1990.  Hydrology. An Introduction to the 
Hydrologyc  Science.  Massachusetts  Institute  of 
Technology.

Comment: Can you provide a link to what the wide function is?

Comment: I do not have a link, but I have that reference. See my edit